# Write operation during a long cursor operation

Tags: mongodb

I use MongoDB 2.4 with a single DB.

I find all items in a collection (50.000+) and for each one, I insert it into another one.

```
it = coll1.find()
while (it.hasNext()) {
  coll2.save(it.next())
}
```

Is it a performance issue to make intensive writes when a cusor is open on the same database ?

Comment: Is the last line a question?

Comment: yes, question updated !

Comment: By the way, what kind of database engine are you using?

Comment: @rpax there's more than one database engine in MongoDB?

Comment: @Sammaye I think the question was edited just after my comment. Or I'm blind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This essentially comes down to a question about concurrency ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/ ) being able to do reads on a single database level writer greedy lock performantly while creating a write intensive load.

MongoDB should be able to juggle your read lock with the write lock quite well here, interweaving operations and yielding the current operation under certain conditions that it sees fit to keep performance up (see link supplied above).

This is, of course, in contrast to SQL where read and write operations are isolated, as such this means that MongoDBs concurrency rules actually break the I in ACID. Of course, in SQL the lock is much more granular so you would get relative performance normally.

If you do see a performance hit, mainly due to IO (reading requires IO as well remember) then you might find it prudent to batch your writes into groups of maybe 1000, taking about a 5 second break after each batch to let the IO subside.

Answer (score 0):

No as cursors are not atomic. Each read is its own atomic transaction. This means that mongo is not subject to the issues of ensuring that the cursor represents a single snapshot in time.